# Failed to create nested attribute in Factory Girl?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I have a `many-to-many` association between a `Post` and a `Category` model:

**categorization.rb:**

```
class Categorization < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :category_id, :post_id, :position

  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :category
end
```

**category.rb:**

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :posts, :through => :categorizations  

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 14 }
end
```

**post.rb:**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :content, :category_ids

  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :categories, :through => :categorizations  

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :categorizations, allow_destroy: true

end
```

*This works:*

**post_spec.rb:**

```
describe Post do

  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  let(:category) { FactoryGirl.create(:category) }
  before { @post = user.posts.build(title: "Lorem ipsum",
                                    content: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
                                    category_ids: category) }
```

*My problem it's here:*

**factories.rb:**

```
  factory :post do
    title "Lorem"
    content "Lorem ipsum"
    category_ids category
    user
  end

  factory :category do
    name "Lorem"
  end
```

**reply_spec.rb:**

```
describe Reply do

  let(:post) { FactoryGirl.create(:post) }
  let(:reply) { post.replies.build(content: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet") }
```

When I run the test for `reply_spec.rb` I get this error:

```
> undefined method `category=' for #<Post:0x9e07564>
```

*This is part that that is not working I think:*

**factories.rb:**

```
  category_ids category
```

Am I defining the nested attribute in a wrong way? What's the proper one?

Comment: Check this link [factory girl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375907/how-can-i-build-create-a-many-to-many-association-in-factory-girl), it's maybe what you need.

Comment: @Kien Thanh Thanks, I think it has useful concepts but I think it is targeted to a `has_and_belongs_to_many` association. Not the `:many => through` I'm using here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this post uses after_build hooks to create associations: [Populating an association with children in factory_girl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937326/populating-an-association-with-children-in-factory-girl)

Personally I like not having factories too complicated (makes them too specific imo), and instead instantiate any neccessary associations in the tests as needed.

factories.rb:

```
factory :post do
  title "Lorem"
  content "Lorem ipsum"
  user
end

factory :category do
  name "Lorem"
end
```

post_spec.rb:

```
...
let(:post) {FactoryGirl.create(:post, :category => FactoryGirl.create(:category))}
```

(edit -- since post object has associations to categorizations and not to categories directly)

```
let(:post) {FactoryGirl.create(:post)}
let(:categorization) {FactoryGirl.create(:categorization, 
                                  :post=> post, 
                                  :category=> FactoryGirl.create(:category))}
```

Comment: Thanks, your code worked with a little modification: `let(:post) {FactoryGirl.create(:post, :category_ids => FactoryGirl.create(:category))}` But how would that code look like in `factories.rb`?

Comment: Documentation says: just `category` would work for the factory definition... i think its better practice to always instantiate the associations in test, rather than making complicated factories. (you risk making your tests too specialized, imo).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sorry, I'm quite new on this, could you give me an example of instantiating this association? (I realized that just adding category to the post factory doesn't work because it is a `many-to-many` association).

Comment: i added an edit to the post, since post has associations to categorizations not to categories directly, which might have been confusing. i prefer to keep the factory definitions simple, and create the associations during tests. hope that makes sense -- i was super confused with ruby testing when i first started out, its definitely a discipline, but makes more sense the more you learn !

Comment: Thanks but I think I'm getting validation errors: `Validation failed: Tag ids can't be blank` I do have a `tag_ids` required field in the posts.